# Cross Compile Android and Dependencies

Tags: android, c, android-ndk, arm, cross-compiling

I am trying to understand cross compile process in more detail.so What I know till now is if we have any C/C++ libraries we can cross compile them to make *.a or *.so files and use them throught JNI in android.

Lets say we have one library source code let it DCMTK source code (a dicom toolkit) which depends on libpng/libxml2 and many others.DCMTK uses CMake as build system.

so what I understand is if I want to use DCMTK in android I need to cross compile it.SO I run the process by CMake-GUI and setup cross compile by cmake-android script. so it does points correct compilers etc for android arm arch.

but I see in the process that cmake takes many libraries from my linux system for example : libpng / libxml2.

Question : As cmake takes some binaries etc from linux(which are compiled for linux system not android )system and We are cross compiling only DCMTK not their dependency so how it will work ? should I cross compile Dependencies too with cross compiler ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, all of DCMTK dependencies must be cross-compiled and linked against [bionic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bionic_(software)) C library and they all must be part of your final app.